# How to let maven run a single test class with non-default profile activated?

Tags: unit-testing, maven-2, junit

I'm trying to let maven run a single test class but I need to use an additional profile (which in fact is already created). Normally when I run:

mvn clean install -PmyProfile

"myProfile" is being activated. So I tried:

mvn -Dtest=myTest -PmyProfile test

Which resulted in "[WARNING] 
    Profile with id: 'myProfile' has not been activated."

What am I doing wrong and how can I achieve my goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot reproduce. I have a "sandbox" profile defined in my `~/.m2/settings.xml` and the following command just works, without complains:

```
$ mvn -Dtest=AppTest -Psandbox test
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Q3372129
[INFO]    task-segment: [test]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
...
```

While using an undefined profile generates the WARNING you're talking about:

```
$ mvn -Dtest=AppTest -Pfoo test
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] 
    Profile with id: 'foo' has not been activated.

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Q3372129
[INFO]    task-segment: [test]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
...
```

This begs the question: where is this profile defined?

Comment: myProfile is defined in my pom.xml. I didn't think of defining profiles in my settings.xml. Thanks a lot for your response.